# How to get sensor values for Android

Tags: android, c, android-emulator, kernel, android-sensors

I am currently building 3.1 kernel for android (tegra/goldfish branch). I would like to write a program in C that gets the sensor values. I do have inc/hardware/sensors.h and some relevant files but I keep getting an error when trying to open the sensor device.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the samples that are packed with the NDK, `native-activity` in particular.

Comment: Is there anything low level? As in to use system calls directly to the driver? Thanks again

Comment: low level ? lower than a function in C ? You want to program in assembly ?

Comment: native-activity is in Java... I would prefer C.

Comment: nope, you are probably confused by the Java API, but i was talking about the samples in the NDK, download the NDK, unpack the archive, look in the samples folder: the entire apk is done without a single row written in java and is only in C/C++.

Comment: So what files would I look at in order to know how to get sensor values?

Comment: @Buffalo the core part of the codebase is in the `jni` folder, here you can find a single file `main.c` with the C source code for the application. To master Android you need to know at least the basics about its own building toolchain and in general how to get from your C/C++ code to an apk, it's not hard, but you need to read something about how to write an Android.mk and an Application.mk; you will find all the infos in the `docs` folder of the NDK, under the folder `platforms` you will find all the headers and libraries.